# How do I target specific rows from two different tables in order to get the difference of the value in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hope you're doing all well. :)

I have been working on an **Attendance Tracking System in Laravel**, where the admin is supposed to check employees in and out.

This is the first table where the checkin is saved:

[image: This is the first table where the checkin is saved]

And this is the checkout table where the leave times are saved:

[image]

As you can see the duration needs to be calculated from the difference of the check-in and check-out from a specific employee.

[image]
[image]

Now my question: How do I target a specific row from the table and calculate its difference. How do I let the system know which row to check-out?

**It might be to complicated to understand, if you have an easier way to do this please let me know, its much appreciated!**

Comment: Do you keep the employ id or something in both tables?

Comment: @Rishni the employee id is in both tables, but you're able to add many rows with the same id in the same table. I think this where it went wrong...

Comment: Instead of maintaining two tables you can maintain this log in a single table and make it easy because if a student do a check in then at the day end user will do a checkout as well. while creating a check in entry you can store null as a checkout and when do checkout set that value. I am thinking work_id is a location id where employee was working. Here you need to add employee id as well so we can identify for which employee this entry is for

Comment: Yes.. This could be easy and perfect if those tables  have relationships.  But now you may try searching using date. But having a relationship is the best way

Comment: @Bhushan work_id is basically the employee_id but how do i target the specific row when checking out?